# Click button, change 2 image

Tags: jquery, html, css, button

I have 2 buttons, and 2 image area. when I click button I want change 2 area. #area image have changed but #area2 image cant. I use double `data-rel`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
        $("#area2").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' class='son' />");
        $(".son").hide().fadeIn(2000);
    });
  
    $("button").click(function() {
    var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
    $("#area").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' class='single-img-vin' />");
    $(".single-img-vin").hide().fadeIn(2000);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="area" src="img1.jpg" class="single-img-vin" alt="">
<img id="area2" src="img-sec1.jpg" class="son">
<ul>
    <li>
        <button class="small-image" data-rel="img1.jpg" data-rel="img-sec-1.jpg"">
        <img src="icon1.png" class="picker-color" />
        </button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="small-image" data-rel="img2.jpg" data-rel="img-sec-2.jpg">
        <img src="icon2.png" class="picker-color">
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're after. Do you want one button to change the first image and another to change the second?

Answer (score 0):

You are binding event listener on same element in both cases. Use id to make them unique.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
        $("#area2").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' class='son' />");
        $(".son").hide().fadeIn(2000);
    });
  
    $("#btn2").click(function() {
    var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
    $("#area").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' class='single-img-vin' />");
    $(".single-img-vin").hide().fadeIn(2000);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="area" src="img1.jpg" class="single-img-vin" alt="">
<img id="area2" src="img-sec1.jpg" class="son">
<ul>
    <li>
        <button id="btn1" class="small-image" data-rel="img1.jpg" data-rel="img-sec-1.jpg"">
        <img src="icon1.png" class="picker-color" />
        </button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button id="btn2" class="small-image" data-rel="img2.jpg" data-rel="img-sec-2.jpg">
        <img src="icon2.png" class="picker-color">
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```